# Close and Open Same Userform To Refresh Data

Tags: excel, vba

I have 2 VBA forms. The Parent form creates a child form, which takes some input and stores it to a global variable. After the child form is closed, the Parent form reads the input and writes it to a file.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Activate()

    'Read and Parse XML File
    'Set eWorkbook = ActiveWorkbook
    Set oXmlFile = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
    xmlUrl = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\DEMO.xml"
    oXmlFile.Load (xmlUrl)
...
```

Now, because the parent form on `UserForm_Activate` reads this newly written file as data source for its `textfields`, I would like to close the Parent form and re-open it once the save function is over, viz.

```
Private Sub cmdNew_Click()
    ufNewEntry.Show
    'Do Stuff
    oXmlFile.Save (xmlUrl)

    'Add form close and re-open current userform function here
     -------------------------------------
End Sub
```

How can this be done? `Me.refresh` does not work.

Comment: Have you tried `Me.Repaint`?

Comment: TimStack Works! Thanks! Just to be sure, the form does reload in the background right? Or atleast the `UserForm_Activate()`?

Comment: Glad you got it working :)

Comment: Just to be sure, the form does reload in the background right? Or atleast the `UserForm_Activate()`

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean

Comment: I mean I understand that `Me.Repaint` reloads the controls and it also works, but is there any more `hardcore` function to actually close and reopen the form? To be absolutely sure that is that the form is re-initiated?

Comment: If you put the dataloading code in a standalone sub (which is called from Userform_Activate) then you can call that sub whenever you like.

Comment: Like @TimWilliams said, you don't have to reopen a userform to update its contained values. You could simply rerun the sub that loaded these values in the first place.